# How do I use the GTGE library? Java 2D games

Tags: import, compilation

I downloaded from the official site a zip containing a jar and a "docs" folder, inside there is a "com" folder and a "resources" folder. I want to be able to use this libray in my java IDE (eclipse) but when i type :  import com.golden.*; it does not recognise the command.

How do I add this library so that I can actually use it with programming? Please be as specific as possible, as I seem to have a natural talent in failing to follow instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click on your project
- Select properties
- Select the Java build path from the list to left side
- Click libraries on the right side
- Click on "Add external JARS"
- Select your file